# Variable membership start date with fixed end date

Tags: civimember

Our client has a membership plan that offers a 3 Month membership but it has to stop for accounting reason by the 31st of August. So if it starts on the 10th of February, end date will be after 3 months on the 9th of May but if it starts on 10th of July it will be ending on the 31st of August. It seems unfair but their work this way.

Is this possible? I only know fixed or variable but not a mix of it.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately that's not possible via UI config, we also had similar request and end up writing extension to support it. So its possible by writing custom code.

Or other option is to make 4 different fixed membership type i.e for each quarter and have 4 different price field in a price set with single option respectively and have Active on and expiry on field set.

Comment: thanks Pradeep. What about a CiviRule to force membership end date?

Comment: would this extension be available for the community?